# Correctly awaiting in F# an async C# method with return type of Task<T>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#, async-await

I'd like to be able to consume a C# library from F#. Mostly this has been pretty straightforward. However, if I try to call a function that returns a `Task<T>` I am not able to get the returned value.

So, I have C# method with the following definition:

```
public async Task<TEvent> ReadEventAsync<TEvent>(string streamName, int position) where TEvent: class
```

And I am trying to consume this method from F# as follows:

```ml
let readEventFromEventStore<'a when 'a : not struct> (eventStore:IEventStoreRepository) (streamName:string) (position:int) = 
     async {
            return eventStore.ReadEventAsync(streamName, position) 
            |> Async.AwaitTask
            }
```

I partially apply this function with an instance of an `IEventStoreRepository` and the stream name I wish to retrieve the event from:

```ml
let readEvent = readEventFromEventStore eventStore streamName
```

Then, finally, I apply the remaining parameter:

```ml
let event = readEvent StreamPosition.Start
```

When I get the value of `event` it is a `FSharpAsync<object>` rather than the `T` from the `Task<T>` that I had expected.

What is the correct method in F# of calling an `async` method written in C# with a return type of `Task<T>` and accessing the value of `T`?

Comment: Try `return! eventStore. ...` rather than `return eventStore. ...`?

Comment: @ildjarn - Just tried it there. Unfortunately, it returns the exact same result i.e. `FSharpAsync<object>`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all, in your use case, there's no need for the `async { }` block. [`Async.AwaitTask` returns an `Async<'T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.awaittask%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D), so your `async { }` block is just unwrapping the `Async` object that you get and immediately re-wrapping it.

Now that we've gotten rid of the unnecessary `async` block, let's look at the type you've gotten, and the type you *wanted* to get. You got an `Async<'a>`, and you want an object of type `'a`. Looking through the [available `Async` functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/control.async-class-%5bfsharp%5d), the one that has a type signature like `Async<'a> -> 'a` is [`Async.RunSynchronously`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.runsynchronously%5b't%5d-method-%5bfsharp%5d). It takes two **optional** parameters, an `int` and a `CancellationToken`, but if you leave those out, you've got the function signature you're looking for. And sure enough, once you look at the docs it turns out that `Async.RunSynchronously` is <del>the F# equivalent of C#'s `await`, which is what you want.</del> sort of (but not exactly) like C#'s `await`. C#'s `await` is a statement you can use inside an `async` function, whereas F#'s `Async.RunSynchronously` takes an `async` object blocks the current thread until that `async` object has finished running. Which is precisely what you're looking for in this case.

```ml
let readEventFromEventStore<'a when 'a : not struct> (eventStore:IEventStoreRepository) (streamName:string) (position:int) =
    eventStore.ReadEventAsync(streamName, position) 
    |> Async.AwaitTask
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

That should get you what you're looking for. And note that technique of figuring out the function signature of the function you need, then looking for a function with that signature. It'll help a LOT in the future.

**Update:** Thank you Tarmil for pointing out my mistake in the comments: `Async.RunSynchronously` is **not** equivalent to C#'s `await`. It's pretty similar, but there are some important subtleties to be aware of since `RunSynchronously` blocks the current thread. (You don't want to call it in your GUI thread.)

**Update 2:** When you want to await an async result without blocking the current thread, it's usually part of a pattern that goes like this:

1. Call some async operation
2. Wait for its result
3. Do something with that result

The best way to write that pattern is as follows:

```
let equivalentOfAwait () =
    async {
        let! result = someAsyncOperation()
        doSomethingWith result
    }
```

The above assumes that `doSomethingWith` returns `unit`, because you're calling it for its side effects. If instead it returns a value, you'd do:

```
let equivalentOfAwait () =
    async {
        let! result = someAsyncOperation()
        let value = someCalculationWith result
        return value
    }
```

Or, of course:

```
let equivalentOfAwait () =
    async {
        let! result = someAsyncOperation()
        return (someCalculationWith result)
    }
```

That assumes that `someCalculationWith` is NOT an async operation. If instead you need to chain together two async operations, where the second one uses the first one's result -- or even three or four async operations in a sequence of some kind -- then it would look like this:

```
let equivalentOfAwait () =
    async {
        let! result1 = someAsyncOperation()
        let! result2 = nextOperationWith result1
        let! result3 = penultimateOperationWith result2
        let! finalResult = finalOperationWith result3
        return finalResult
    }
```

Except that `let!` followed by `return` is exactly equivalent to `return!`, so that would be better written as:

```
let equivalentOfAwait () =
    async {
        let! result1 = someAsyncOperation()
        let! result2 = nextOperationWith result1
        let! result3 = penultimateOperationWith result2
        return! (finalOperationWith result3)
    }
```

All of these functions will produce an `Async<'T>`, where `'T` will be the return type of the final function in the `async` block. To actually *run* those async blocks, you'd either do `Async.RunSynchronously` as already mentioned, or you could use one of the various `Async.Start` functions (`Start`, `StartImmediate`, `StartAsTask`, `StartWithContinuations`, and so on). The [`Async.StartImmediate` example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.startimmediate-method-%5bfsharp%5d) talks a little bit about the [`Async.SwitchToContext` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.switchtocontext-method-%5bfsharp%5d) as well, which may be something you'll want to read about. But I'm not familiar enough with `SynchronizationContext`s to tell you more than that.

Comment: That nailed it. Thanks. And also thanks for the pointer re looking at the function signatures.

Comment: Uh, there's a bit of misinformation in here. Namely, `Async.RunSynchronously` is most definitely *not* the F# equivalent of C#'s `await`. It's more like C#'s `task.Wait()`, ie it blocks the current thread until the task has completed. `let!` in an `async {}` block is F#'s equivalent of `await`.

Comment: @Tarmil - Thanks for catching that! Fixed my misinformation; hopefully the answer is now fully correct after the edit.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Is there any way in F# to await (sic) the result of an async C# method **without** blocking the current thread (and without requiring the original `SynchronizationContext` to be restored on resumption of the following code)? I guess I mean to say: is there a precise F# equivalent `await SomeAsyncMethod().ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `ConfigureAwait()` to be sure of the subtleties, but in F#, the general pattern is that inside an `async` block, you can use `let! result = someAsyncOperation()`. Note the exclamation mark. This will await `someAsyncOperation`, and then bind its value to `result`. I'll update my answer with more details, since a comment isn't the best place to write code samples.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using the `async` computation expression for this situation (F# calling C# Task-based XxxAsync method) is to use the `task` computation expression from:

https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs

The Giraffe F# web framework uses `task` for more or less the same reason:

https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe/blob/develop/DOCUMENTATION.md#tasks