# How to ignore C# awaitable Task when consumed from F#?

Tags: .net-core, f#, async-await

I am trying to make the code below working

```ml
type Message = {
    Text: string
}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    use bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost")
    async {
        let! result = bus.PubSub.PublishAsync({Text = "text"}) |> Async.AwaitTask
    }
    0
```

Knowing that `PublishAsync` returns `Task<unit>`. I just wanted to equivalently `await` this method in F# method but this triggers an error:

```
Program.fs(14, 5): [FS0010] Unexpected symbol '}' in expression
```

I already checked [that answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41744021/4636721), not really sure what I am supposed to do, adding `|> ignore` does not seem to do anything.

[EDIT]

I added an `ignore`:

```ml
type Message = {
    Text: string
}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    use bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost")
    async {
        let! result = bus.PubSub.PublishAsync({Text = "text"}) |> Async.AwaitTask
        result |> ignore
    }
    0
```

But now I get the following warning:

> `Program.fs(10, 5)`: `[FS0020]` The result of this expression has type `'Async<unit>'` and is implicitly ignored. Consider using `'ignore'` to discard this value explicitly, e.g. `'expr |> ignore'`, or `'let'` to bind the result to a name, e.g. `'let result = expr'`.

Can't get rid of that one though, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of this expression:

```
async {
    let! result = bus.PubSub.PublishAsync({Text = "text"}) |> Async.AwaitTask
    result |> ignore
}
```

is a value of `Async<unit>` type. In F# and functional programming, every expression should contribute to the result of the bigger expression, otherwise it is likely a mistake. Hence your compiler reported the warning.

To tell compiler that you are okay with that, simply transform the value to the `()` value of the `unit` type (which is similar to `void` type in other languages) by using the `ignore` function.

Now look into the body of your `async`, in your old code, the last statement is `let! result = ...` and it is invalid in F# syntax. Every `let` or `let!` is the short form of `let name=... in someExpression` but there is no expression here except the `}` that’s why compiler said `Unexpected symbol '}' in expression`.

You fixed that by piping `result` to `ignore`. That’s okay because that is a valid expression.

Now consider your new code, you can ignore the `Async<unit>` to dismiss the warning, but that makes your `async` nonsense. You declared the `async`, but did not execute it. Probably you need to execute it with the `Async.RunSynchronously` function:

```
async {
    let! result = bus.PubSub.PublishAsync({Text = "text"}) |> Async.AwaitTask
    result |> ignore
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Since `result` is a `unit` value, you can clean your code with `do!`:

```
async {
    do! bus.PubSub.PublishAsync({Text = "text"}) |> Async.AwaitTask
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Or even cleaner:

```
bus.PubSub.PublishAsync({Text = "text"})
|> Async.AwaitTask
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41744021/4636721 and the source code of `Async.RunSynchronously`: "`Async.RunSynchronously` is most definitely NOT the F# equivalent of C#'s await. It's more like C#'s `task.Wait()`, ie it blocks the current thread until the task has completed. `let!` in an `async {}` block is F#'s equivalent of `await`."

Comment: You’re right! But after all what you got is a value of type Async, and you have to decide what you will do with it. If you decide to use it inside another async, then let! is your friend. If you decide to execute it, go with Async.Run/StartXXX. In many other cases, you would pass it to another library that requires an async value. It’s up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `async` computation expression returns `Async<unit>`. You need to actually run the computation. You can do that with `Async.RunSynchronously`.

```
async {
    let! result = bus.PubSub.PublishAsync({Text = "text"}) |> Async.AwaitTask
    result |> ignore
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Though at this point, I think the computation expression is redundant. This would do the same:

```
bus.PubSub.PublishAsync({Text = "text"})
|> Async.AwaitTask
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: except that this is not what I want: "C#'s `await` is a statement you can use inside an `async` function, whereas F#'s `Async.RunSynchronously` takes an async object >>blocks the current thread until that `async` object has finished running<<." Which is not equivalent, I want to benefit from the fact I am not using up a dedicated thread and benefit from an IO bound operation.

Comment: @EhouarnPerret You can use `Async.StartImmediate` to run the computation without waiting for it to finish, but if you do that then your console app is going to exit before anything happens.

Comment: there is no way the console is freeing the current thread and resume later on on another thread once the IO bound operation is done, just like "`await` myAwaitableMethod"?

Comment: @EhouarnPerret you'd have to block in C# too. Though C# 7.1 adds [`async Main` support](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main.md), all it does under the covers is call `Main().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

Comment: really? Damn, I didn't know that. So for a simple console application, every `async` IO bound calls are going to be boiled down to wait on the current thread?